# vue.js - ELEMENT UI upload button color change

Tags: html, css, vue.js, element-ui

I am using upload image file button from element ui which is shown in
[this link](https://element-plus.run/#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).
However, I need to change color of button from blue to green same as another button which is shown in  below picture.

[image]

Can you help me to edit style of the button?
Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to:

```
 <el-button type="success">Click to upload</el-button>
```

And also look at the [documentation](https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/button.html)